# Node to s3 403 Error when trying to send plain text

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, mime-types

Trying to take plain text and send it to s3 -- getting a 403 error. Am able to do pdfs, so I know certain things like my key credentials are not important.

I understand the MIME type text/plain to include strings, such as those that might be entered into a textarea html element.

My options post:

```
OPTIONS /simplelogin%3A27/Bill?AWSAccessKeyId=MYKEYID&Content-MD5=&Content-Type=text%2Fplain&Expires=1435969411&Signature=MYSIGNATURE&x-

amz-acl=public-read HTTP/1.1
Host: documents.s3.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://localhost:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:9000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

My 403 request put:

```
PUT /simplelogin%3A27/BILL?AWSAccessKeyId=MYKEY&Content-MD5=&Content-

Type=text%2Fplain&Expires=1435969411&Signature=MYSIGNATURE&x-amz-acl=public-read HTTP/1.1
Host: documents.s3.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 10
Origin: http://localhost:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:9000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
AWSAccessKeyId:SECRET KEY
Content-MD5:
Content-Type:text/plain
Expires:1435969411
Signature:SECRETSIG
x-amz-acl:public-read
Request Payload
adsaasdfaf
```

I know there is no Content-MD5, but that doesn't affect the pdf/docx upload.

My code:

```
function getGenericSignedUrl (res, bucket, pathToFileWithFileName, filetype, access) {

if(!access) {
    access = 'public-read';
}

// set up cred
aws.config.update({accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY});

// get s3 object
var s3 = new aws.S3();

// what we're storing and where
var options = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: pathToFileWithFileName,
    Expires: 90,
    ACL: access,
    ContentMD5: '',
    ContentType: filetype
}

s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', options, function(err, data) {

    if(err) return res.send('Error with S3');

    // formatted url for preview access
    var parsedUrl = url.parse(data);
    parsedUrl.search = null;
    var objectUrl = url.format(parsedUrl);

    // return signed url for upload and clickable url
    res.json({
        signed_request: data,
        url_: objectUrl
    });


});
```

}

Comment: I strongly suggest using the Amazon SDK.  It makes this sort of thing really easy, and is quite efficient under Node.js.

Comment: @Brad Hey Brad, I do use the SDK. I was just showing the code from the headers because I thought that is where the error could be spotted. Anyway, I've updated with my code.